The image uploader has stopped working
The image uploader isn’t working today (3rd of May 2024).
I’m trying to upload an PNG image that is 400 px wide, and only 46 KB.  The uploader tries for about 20 seconds, but eventually gives up:

An error occurred, please try again.

(And I did try again, but it still isn’t working.)

Now it seems to be fixed.

I had an issue few minutes ago when I tried to log in. Maybe it was related.

I had this issue too (around 50 mins previous to now). Also now fixed for me!

No repro now, might be erratic, or location based.

I have the problem in Chrome Chrome is up to date Version 124.0.6367.119 (Official Build) (64-bit) but the image feature works fine in Firefox Firefox is up to date 125.0.3 (64-bit) I am using Windows 11 version 23H2 22631.3527.

But then it doesn't! Seems to be intermittent
